# Datepicker disable before specific day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two datepicker which include starting and ending date.

When the first date is chosed, i want to disable before chosen first date's, dates in ending date. Also disable after today.

[image: START DATE]
[image: END DATE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
<input type="text" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom" readonly="true" value="" class="textbox" />
<input type="text" name="dateTo" id="dateTo" readonly="true" value="" class="textbox" />


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dateFrom").datepicker({
            onClose: function () {
                $("#dateTo").datepicker(
                    "change", {
                    minDate: new Date($('#dateFrom').val())
                });
               $("#dateFrom").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
            }
        });

        $("#dateTo").datepicker({
            onClose: function () {
                $("#dateFrom").datepicker(
                    "change", {
                    maxDate: new Date($('#dateTo').val())
                });
                $("#dateTo").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

See working example here. https://jsfiddle.net/jjLhca9o/

**Edit:**

See Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjLhca9o/5/

Comment: it works thanks, but how can i change format to dd/mm/yy. If i change, val' s month changed to day